# Setting a timer for a long period of time error: Expo, React Native, Firestore, Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm receiving the following error on my React Native Expo app:

```
Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
(Saw setTimeout with duration 3062719ms)
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:117:10 in registerWarning
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:63:8 in warnImpl
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:36:4 in console.warn
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/react-native-logs.fx.js:18:4 in warn
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:226:6 in setTimeout
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:30:83 in <anonymous>
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:30:259 in <anonymous>
* http://192.168.0.19:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:174354:14 in B
* http://192.168.0.19:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:175128:18 in od
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:270:434 in A$argument_0
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:270:4 in a.ia.then$argument_0
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:276:328 in dl.prototype.o
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:315:197 in ym
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:315:575 in Bm
* http://192.168.0.19:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:174501:26 in <unknown>
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:19:290 in <anonymous>
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:19:222 in <anonymous>
* http://192.168.0.19:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false:174578:10 in Zb
- node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth.js:13:433 in Ja
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue
```

It's specifically causing issues when I attempt to run the program on my Android phone, when I go through the process of logging in. Here's the code that handles the login action:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
  .then(() => {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(getUser({
          email: res.user.email,
          uid: res.user.uid,
          emailVerified: res.user.emailVerified
        }))
      }).catch(e => {
        setEmailError('That username/password combination is incorrect. Please try again.')
      })
  })
```

It sets persistence of the firebase auth state, logs in with the credentials the user provided, then dispatches the action to the Redux store to save the user details and authentication in the global state.

The change in state should trigger the re-rendering of the app, as at the root of my application I conditionally render one of two navigators based on the isAuthenticated state:

```
const ProjectRootFile = (props, { isAuthenticated }) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      { isAuthenticated ? (
        <DrawerNavigator />
      ) : (
        <AuthNavigator />
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.userReducer.user,
  isAuthenticated: state.userReducer.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProjectRootFile);
```

When I run the application in my browser and log in everything works correctly. It returns the successful log in from Firestore, the user data is saved in the Redux Store, and I'm redirected to the dashboard as I should.

But when I attempt to do this on my Android device I receive the error mentioned above, the app freezes up, and it crashes after a minute or so. I haven't attempted to run this on an ios device yet as I code on Linux and I can't use the expo ios simulator on it, but I'm going to drag out my old Macbook Air in a minute to test out that side of things as well.

This issue has been discussed ad nauseum in many other posts, and one of the most common workarounds is to go into the node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js file, and update the const MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS = 60 * 1000; field to a larger number, like 60000 * 1000.

But that doesn't solve the problem for me. The only difference is I no longer see the error, but the app still freezes up and crashes without ever logging the user in and redirecting them to the correct page.

Is there something wrong with the logic of my code? I don't understand why it would work fine on the browser, but have issues on an Android device.

Answer (score -1):

i am currently using this

```
 react-native-background-timer
```

for the updating of my apps news feed every 5 mins and it seems to work perfect for it just make sure you cancel all timers before a user leaves the screen as this can cause issues if you dont

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the timer error is very common, and often a red herring of another issue. Turned out to be a problem with how I was using props vs destructuring them. App's up and running again!